# How to fetch messages from database using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have a simple messaging system in PHP, I can send messages into a database without refreshing the page but, I also want to display already sent messages to the database instantly using ajax, jquery or any other method. (on both sides sender and receiver)

my Html:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <input autofocus autocomplete="off" name="typed_msg" id="typed_msg" >
   <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

My JS code:

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           var typed_msg = $('#typed_msg').val();
           var receiver_id = $('#receiver_id').val();
           if(typed_msg == '')  
           {  
                $('#error_msg').html("Message blank!");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $('#error_msg').html('');  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"msg.php",  
                     method:'post',  
                     data:{typed_msg:typed_msg, receiver_id:receiver_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $("form").trigger("reset");  
                          $('#succ_msg').fadeIn().html(data);  
                          setTimeout(function(){  
                               $('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow");  
                          }, 2000);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });

 </script>
```

Messages display code:

```html
<ul style="list-style:none;width:90%">
<li>
<p>
      <?php
      if($msg_senderID == $_SESSION['id']){?>
         <img src="media/<?php echo $userProfileImg;?>" alt="" style="position:absolute;right:0;margin-top:-5px;margin-left:-70px;">
    <?php      
      } else {?>
         <img src="media/<?php echo $senderImg;?>" alt="" style="margin-top:-5px;margin-left:-70px;">
    <?php
      } 
       
       ?> <?php echo $msg_body;?>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For two way messaging, Web Sockets are the most appropriate. Try socket.io: https://socket.io/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, is there any easy guideline for starting (adding to existing project)?

Comment: I have never actually used it myself, but it seems it's only for nodejs. The alternative for PHP is https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

Comment: Thanks, i definitely will try to use this

Answer (score 0):

For two way messaging, Web Sockets are the most appropriate.

Try socket.io: https://socket.io/

It's alternative for PHP: https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

You need to use the first one for client side since it's in JS, and the second one on server side. Create the socket on server side first and connect client side to same port. Check out the Hello World version of socket.io.

Comment: But I need in PHP and MySQLi along with ajax, do you have plz any comments?

Comment: @JuncBook Check the hello world and examples of both.